# write pandas iterrows output to file

Tags: python, pandas

two dataframes

df1:

```
ch  start   end strand  5ss 3ss
3   90280167    90280927    +   90280167    90280927
3   90280167    90281242    +   90280167    90281242
3   90280986    90281242    +   90280986    90281242
3   90281284    90284526    +   90281284    90284526
5   33977824    33984550    -   33984550    33977824
```

df2:

```
ch  start   end strand  5ss 3ss
3   90280167    90281242    +   90280167    90281242
5   33977824    33984550    -   33984550    33977824
```

Code:

```
c1 = []
c = 0 
for ii,rr in df1.iterrows():
    c1.append(rr)


c2 = []
with open('3prime.txt', 'w') as w:  
     for i,r in df2.iterrows():
         c2.append(r)
     for i in c1:
         for j in c2:
             start = int(1[4])
             end = int(i[5])
             fivep = int(j[4])
             threep = int(j[5])

             if start == fivep:
                print i
```

Output:

```
ch                                      3
start                            90280167
end                              90280927
strand                                  +
5ss                              90280167
3ss                              90280927
ch                                      5
start                            33983577
end                              33984550
strand                                  -
5ss                              33984550
3ss                              33983577
```

desired output:

```
ch  start   end strand  5ss 3ss
3   90280167    90281242    +   90280167    90281242 #from df1
3   90280167    90281242    +   90280167    90281242 # fromdf2
5   33977824    33984550    -   33984550    33977824 # fromdf1
5   33977824    33984550    -   33984550    33977824 #fromdf2
```

problem1: when I try to write to file I get a blank file, secondly I would like to do this as well  `if start == fivep:` is true then

print i and the next line print j

some thing like this

```
print i +'\n' + j
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

then i try this

```
print str(i) + '\n' + str(j)
```

What that means is basically first line from df1 that matched and second line from df2 that matched have the line that matched in both the

when i try the second print statement i get the same output as first print statement (print i) but now with elements from j, can some one please guide me how should I approach this problem.

Comment: `print i` does not write to file. It writes to the standard output (console). You need `w.write(str(i)+'\n')`. You also need to move `with open('3prime.txt', 'w') ...` outside of all loops, otherwise each iteration overwrites the previously written content.

Comment: I still do not get the out put as desired still get the same thing as i have printed in the question

Comment: Which rows are you trying to select? All rows present in both dataframes?

Comment: yes, all rows that match the condition. but while writing keep row one from d1 and then row2 from df2

Comment: why does `DATAFRAME_NAME.to_csv(PATH_HERE)` not work?

Comment: because I iterating over two dfs and my results held by i and j which i guess(correct me if i am wrong) not a df

Comment: Could you clarify the condition? That's what I'm trying to ask after.

Comment: `if start == fivep:` is the condition, if this is true then get both the rows that were true from both the dfs

Comment: So, to clarify, if the `5ss` field from the two dfs match?

Comment: yes. they do match

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip using `iterrows` by building the dataframe you want, then saving it with `df.to_csv('desired/path/to/file.csv')`?

For example, using what I understand to be your criteria, something like

```
out1 = df1.merge(df2, on='5ss', suffixes=['', '_y'])[df1.columns]
out2 = df2.merge(df1, on='5ss', suffixes=['', '_y'])[df2.columns]
pd.concat(out1, out2).sort_index().to_csv('3prime.txt')
```

should do what you want.